# Why can a constructor be used without `new` keyword in Javascript?

Tags: object-oriented, javascript, functional-programming, prototyping

I found Date can be used without the `new` keyword.

```
Date(1)
> "Thu May 28 2015 15:54:20 GMT+0800 (CST)"
new Date(1)
> Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

I was wondering whether there is any side-effect of using it without `new`.. Why would it be designed like this?

Comment: Answer 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascripts-new-keyword-considered-harmful
Answer 2: JavaScript was (mis-)designed in a terrible hurry - mere 10 days.

Comment: Short answer:  because it may not be supported in future versions.  That should be plenty reason to prefer using new.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fundamental Difference between fn() and new fn() in javascript](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/182433/fundamental-difference-between-fn-and-new-fn-in-javascript)

Comment: @Neil: Why do you think it might not be supported in future versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript a constructor is just an ordinary function. Any function which can be called as a constructor with '`new`' can be called as an ordinary function. But functions will almost always be written as *either* a constructor or non-constructor function, and using it the other way is an error.

The built-in objects however are specifically designed so that you can use them both ways (as constructor and as ordinary functions) with two different results. For example `new Date(1)` creates a new Date object (as you would expect for a constructor) while `Date(1)` returns a string representation of the corresponding date, which is perhaps more surprising.